# Function not executing but celery is working

Tags: django, django-views, celery

the `auto_sms` function is working when executed manually on views.py but then I tried to call/do it on tasks.py but its not working. what might be I'm missing here? Thanks!

```
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://:******************************//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
[2021-01-10 23:50:55,743: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2021-01-10 23:50:55,787: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
[2021-01-10 23:51:27,004: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task scheduled_task (app1.tasks.auto_sms)
[2021-01-10 23:51:55,787: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task scheduled_task (app1.tasks.auto_sms)
[2021-01-10 23:52:25,790: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task scheduled_task (app1.tasks.auto_sms)
```

@tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from app1.views import send_sms
from datetime import timedelta
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.timezone import now
from app1.models import Rainfall

@shared_task(name="auto_sms")
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=1),
    )

    count = responses.count()
    if not (count % 10) and count > 0:
        send_sms(request)

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

@settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "scheduled_task": {
        "task": "app1.tasks.auto_sms",
        "schedule": 30.0,
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check the celery worker logs? anything special?

Comment: Hello, im getting this error now. `celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task Task1: auto_sms() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`